# How to identify mobile native traffic in a web app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, referrer, http-referer

Let's say a mobile native application on iOS or Android has a link to Website X.

When a user clicks the link inside the mobile native application, there would be no HTTP referrer headers to look at.

Is there any other way to reliably identify such traffic without the mobile native application doing anything extra like specifically setting an HTTP header?

Comment: A Web browser is a mobile native application.

Comment: It is, but I mean from some other non-web browser application.

Comment: Anything that a mobile native application (Web browser) can do, a mobile native application (non-web browser) can do.